# submenu for desktop and mobile menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, submenu

I am trying to create just 1 submenu for just 1 item in navigation bar in desktop that shows up in mobile devices too.
can anyone help with code? This is part of my code. My codes work good. I do not wanna change whole structure. I need just couple of hyperlinks for one navigation menu link that I show here. I put code at the end. FYI: I have SPAN instead of “toggle “to work for mobile devices hamburger menu.it works without problem.my whole website is without JavaScript. But I am sure for this issue I need JavaScript.I have CSS and html only.I need this so called drop down menu (submenu) works for mobile and desktop devices. My codes already work without issue for desktop and mobile.let’s call those drop down hyperlinks “Link1,Link2,Link3 etc.” to be on same page. Please tell me where to put JavaScript in my html too. The navigation menu link name is called “MyLinks” as I showed here in my codes for you to make it easier:
Here is html code:

```
<div class="nav">
        <input type="checkbox" id="nav-check">
        <div class="nav-header">
               </div>
                <div class="nav-btn">
          <label for="nav-check">
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
          </label>
    </div>
     
        <div class="nav-links" >
            <ul>
          
          <li><a href="MyLinks.html">MyLinks</a></li>
          
          
            </ul>
        </div>
    
        </div>
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: We would need the css code to see how the nav and nav-links work. Also you need to provide your attempt at solving this, for e.g. provide a static submenu, and ask how you can make it appear on click/hover, whatever it is that you want.